# React-Select in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

i'm new to react-redux and i want to create a dropdown with react-select. I created my DropDown component like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

const options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

const MyDropdown = ({ input }) => (
  <div>
    <Select
      {...input}
      value="one"
      options={options}
      multi={true}
      onBlur={() => {
        input.onBlur([...input.value]);
      }
    }
    />
  </div>
);

MyDropdown.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default MyDropdown;
```

and i render in here

```
<Field
            id="status"
            name="status"
            component={MyDropdown}
          />
```

My it got me an annoying error that "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined". What's going on?

Comment: Where is 'Field' coming from? Is that a Bootstrap thing?

Comment: Field is being imported from redux-form

Comment: We enter right know value={input.value}

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error? How are you importing `MyDropdown`? Since `MyDropdown` is undefined, it's possible that the problem is with the import.

Answer (score 1):

In your Form for field:

```
const options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

<Field
            id="status"
            name="status"
            component={MyDropdown}
            options={options}
            clearable={false}
          />
```

Your component should look something like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const MyDropdown = ({ input, ...props }) => {
 const handleBlur = () => input.onBlur
 return (
   <div>
        <Select
          instanceId={input.name}
          {...input}
          {...props}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
   </div>
 )
}
```

If this didn't work check the options passed to it and create a custom method inside your MyDropdown component to generate options from the list you passed and pass it as props to `<select/>`. That should work though.

Comment: How would you pass Value from Field down into Select though? This is currently the problem I am having :O?

Comment: @Jamie Hutber options in the Field is the list of key value pairs passed to the Select in MyDropdown component.

Comment: Ah, so you would put value inside the `options`.... very nice thank you my friend!!